# How can I send email notification via SNS using cloud custodian

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, cloudcustodian

I am trying to configure an custodian policy which will do some basic filtering and send the details of the match to specific user via mail(SNS).

I can able to send the email to the user but I couldn't edit the mail subject or mail body, instead am getting default mail subject and some random text in mail body.

My custodian policy:

```
policies:
  - name: iam-user-permission-check
    resource: aws.iam-user
    description: |
      Finding IAM users with specific tags.
    filters:
      - and:
        - type: check-permissions
          match: allowed
          actions:
            - '*:*'
        - "tag:c7n": "absent"
    actions:
      - type: notify
        subject: "IAM Users Without Proper Tags"
        template: |
          The following IAM users match the filter criteria:
          {% for user in resources %}
          - IAM User: {{ user.UserName }}
            Tags: {{ user.Tags }}
          {% endfor %}
        transport:
         type: sns
         topic: <sns-topic-arn>
         region: us-east-1
```

I did some research, all I get it to use c7n-mailer with SES by passing SQS queue in mailer.html, can't it be done by using SNS?

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score -1):

Look at input transformer or Lambda option to modify the email notification body and only receive a required content.

I had these settings many times and worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).